# selecting gnome interface on ubuntu studio over ubuntu desktop 14.04

Tags: unity, gnome

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu studio over Ubuntu desktop 14.04. I have installed gnome shell and the session too. I am unable to select the interface during login. Please help.